# Chrome Dev Tools: Mapped link disappears after rule is edited in Inspector Styles pane

Tags: google-chrome, less, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Chrome Dev Tools to work with my LESS generated CSS.

My source maps are working correctly and I can see the name and line number of the source file next to the rule in the **Styles** pane of the element inspector.

**Once I make a change in the inspector, the name/link to the source file disappears. Why is this?**

This is frustrating as I have my dev tools set up to edit the source files in Chrome (in the **Source** pane). After checking the change in the inspector, I want to easily jump to the source file to make the change there.

**Update**
I am running Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04 in a VM. On my host (Ubuntu 14.04), instead of the link to the file disappearing, it is replaced with the link to the compiled CSS file.

Comment: Seems like this is a confirmed issue with no solution yet. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=257778